# How to get JSON value in recordset object from SQL Server with a NODE JS query?

Tags: node.js, json, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

With the following code I can get a recordset from the SQL query:

```
const sql = require('mssql');

const config = {
user: 'sa',
password: '1234',
server: 'localhost', 
database: 'pruebas',
options: { trustServerCertificate: true }
};

let getAutos = async () => {
  try {
      await sql.connect(config);
      let db = new sql.Request();
      let consulta = `declare @resultado nvarchar(max);
      set @resultado = (select autos.marca, autos.modelo,
            (select especificaciones.especificacion from autos inner join especificaciones on autos.id_auto = especificaciones.id_auto for json path) as especificaciones
            from autos for json path, root('autos'))
      select @resultado`;
      let datos = await db.query(consulta);
      return datos;
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      throw err;
  }
}

getAutos()
.then(datos => {
  console.log(datos.recordset[0]);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(`Hubo un error`);
});
```

This is the JSON object obtained:

> {
> '': '{"autos":[{"marca":"Ford","modelo":"Mustang","especificaciones":[{"especificacion":"Potencia: 350 HP"},{"especificacion":"Velocidad: 255 km\/h"},{"especificacion":"Cilindrada: 3500 cc"},{"especificacion":"Peso: 1340 Kg"},{"especificacion":"Potencia: 345 HP"},{"especificacion":"Velocidad: 250 km\/h"},{"especificacion":"Cilindrada: 3700 cc"},{"especificacion":"Peso: 1580 Kg"},{"especificacion":"Potencia: 320 HP"},{"especificacion":"Velocidad: 230 km\/h"},{"especificacion":"Cilindrada: 3900 cc"},{"especificacion":"Peso: 1800 Kg"}]},{"marca":"Chevrolet","modelo":"Camaro","especificaciones":[{"especificacion":"Potencia: 350 HP"},{"especificacion":"Velocidad: 255 km\/h"},{"especificacion":"Cilindrada: 3500 cc"},{"especificacion":"Peso: 1340 Kg"},{"especificacion":"Potencia: 345 HP"},{"especificacion":"Velocidad: 250 km\/h"},{"especificacion":"Cilindrada: 3700 cc"},{"especificacion":"Peso: 1580 Kg"},{"especificacion":"Potencia: 320 HP"},{"especificacion":"Velocidad: 230 km\/h"},{"especificacion":"Cilindrada: 3900 cc"},{"especificacion":"Peso: 1800 Kg"}]},{"marca":"Dodge","modelo":"Charger","especificaciones":[{"especificacion":"Potencia: 350 HP"},{"especificacion":"Velocidad: 255 km\/h"},{"especificacion":"Cilindrada: 3500 cc"},{"especificacion":"Peso: 1340 Kg"},{"especificacion":"Potencia: 345 HP"},{"especificacion":"Velocidad: 250 km\/h"},{"especificacion":"Cilindrada: 3700 cc"},{"especificacion":"Peso: 1580 Kg"},{"especificacion":"Potencia: 320 HP"},{"especificacion":"Velocidad: 230 km\/h"},{"especificacion":"Cilindrada: 3900 cc"},{"especificacion":"Peso: 1800 Kg"}]}]}'
> }

How could I access the JSON array?

Why does SQL Server wrap key and value with single quotes? These are not allowed in JSON format.

P.S: If I do not use `FOR JSON PATH` clause recordset reading is fine, but I need nested selects for sub-objects.

Comment: Everything outside the `[...]` is added by your NodeJS code. You probably want to `select @resultado as something`, deserialize the JSON returned from `resultado.recordset[0].something` and finally return that object from your function.

Comment: what would be ".something"?. I edited the query to get a key for the array value but resultado.recordset[0].autos is not working

Comment: `select @resultado` doesn't have a column name, so something as in `select @resultado as anythingYouWantButNotAnEmptyColumnName`.

Comment: I can see clearly now...even though I'm not Jimmy Cliff...I really appreciate your help, thank you !!